# Magento's webservice returns a session even if credentials are not complete

Tags: web-services, magento, authentication

I have a 1.10.1.1 Magento Enterprise version running and tried out the webservice. If I correctly login I get a session id which I can use to make further calls to the web service.

If I leave either the user or password field empty or both empty and want to login I also get a session id. But if I then want to call another method with this session id I get the message I have to relogin.

If I use wrong credentials (both user and password are filled with something) I get a message "Access denied".

So why do I get a session id I can't use if i leave one field (user/password) empty and why don't I get a message "Acces denied" then? Is this an error?